# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException

Tags: java, spring

i have a very basic program but no matter what I change in the code I always get the same Error Message:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-29 17:03:01.228 ERROR 6260 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'queryRepoImp'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queryRepoImp' defined in file [C:\Dropbox\Projects\h2TestEnv\target\classes\com\example\demo\QueryRepoImp.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp bundle
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queryRepoImp' defined in file [C:\Dropbox\Projects\h2TestEnv\target\classes\com\example\demo\QueryRepoImp.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp bundle
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp bundle
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp bundle
    at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1946) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:554) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:553) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp.<init>(QueryRepoImp.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    QueryRepoImp queryRepoImp;

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner clr() {

        return a -> {
            /*
            System.out.println("Create Queries");
            Query c1 = new Query("Wood");
            Query c2 = new Query("Stones");

            // insert
            repo.add(c1);
            repo.add(c2);

            for (Query t : repo.findAll()) {
                System.out.println("Query: " + t.getRelation());
            }


            */
        };
    }
}
```

**QueryRepoImp.java**

```
@Repository
public class QueryRepoImp implements QueryIRepoInt {

    private final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO query (section) VALUES (?)";
    private final String SQL_FINDALL = "SELECT * FROM query ORDER BY lastname";
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("QueryLogger", QueryRepoImp.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void add(Query query) {
        Object[] objects = {query};
        List<Object[]> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(objects);
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL_INSERT, list);
    }
}
```

**QueryIRepoInt.java**

```
@Component
public interface QueryIRepoInt {
    void add(Query query);
}
```

Can someone tell me please where the error hides? Thank you!

Comment: And you configuration context file/class is...?

Comment: Hi Anna,
You can add a separate configuration file with @Configuration file or add

Comment: Try removing `@Repository` from the implementation class and change `@Component` to `@Repository`

Comment: @Andremoniy if I am it right, I don't have to use/fill that file with springboot manually?. To the other ideas, it didn't help but thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the stacktrace carefully. The cause of your problem is written there.

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.example.demo.QueryRepoImp bundle
```

This resource-bundle is missing. Check if it is part of your project and recheck. (Or you want to use the LoggerFactory to get a logger instance.)

If you have nested exceptions like this, please check every exception.

Comment: I just removed the Logger part and now it is working. But to be honest, I dont understand why. I assume it is because the Logger class is not annotated with @Beans right? How could I solve this when I need the logger? But wow, I was sitting 2 hours in front of that searching in a complete different direction. So, thank you so far :)

Comment: No, you are using a method which requires a ResourceBundle. See the Javadoc for java.util.logging.Logger#getLogger(String, String). But using the LoggerFactory is usually the better approach

Answer (score 2):

Please use following tags in your DemoApplication class.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"Packages you want to scan"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("Repository package")
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication
{
      /*Main method*/
}
```